# concatenation of HTML from return functions

Tags: php, drupal

My controller is looking something like this.

Each of the methods called generate some HTML. The concatenated HTML variable gives the final render of the page

Is there a better way to generate my HTML to render coming from different functions:

```
 $html = $renderer->render($clear_form);
 $html .= $this->render_preview();
 $config = \Drupal::config('amu_import_ldap.settings');
 if (null != $config) {
   $submits = $config->get('import_submits');
   $html .= $this->render_ldap_imports($submits);
 }
 $build = [
  '#markup' => Markup::create("
            {$html}
        "),
];
return $build;
```

Comment: Hello Matoeil. Unfortunately your question has gained a close vote for missing a description. Please can you explain what your code does, currently your description means nothing to me. Given how small the code is it should be easy to explain everything it does.

Comment: each of the methods called generate some html. The concatenenated html variable gives the final render of the page

Comment: @Matoeil: Please [edit] your question to include that description.

Comment: this is done...

Comment: That wasn't much of an improvement. Please see our [FAQ on asking questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2436/how-to-get-the-best-value-out-of-code-review-asking-questions).

Comment: Instead of concatenating, using the `.=` operator, it is more memory efficient to put the parts into an array, like `$html = []; $html[] = "...";` and at the end concatenate it: `$result = implode($html);`

Answer (score 1):

Use a template engine like Twig, Plates or Blade.

You should have base layouts, partials and templates.